# Adding segment or sub-function/class to codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, uri

I have a controller, **digital**, and within that controller one of my functions is widget and then several public functions for widgets, such as **highlights**.

View is set up as digital/widgets/highlights.php

I'd like to have the url display as domain.com/digital/widget/highlights as well as the breadcrumb (autocrumb)

```
public function widget()
{
$header["pageTitle"] = "TV Listing Widgets and Snippets";

$this->load->helper('breadcrumb');

$this->load->view('templates/header.php', $header);
$this->load->view('digital/widget');
$this->load->view('templates/modal.php');
$this->load->view('templates/footer.php');
}


public function highlights()
{
$header["pageTitle"] = "TV Highlights Widget";

$this->load->helper('breadcrumb');

$this->load->view('templates/header.php', $header);
$this->load->view('digital/widgets/highlights');
$this->load->view('templates/modal.php');
$this->load->view('templates/footer.php');
}
```

Is it possible to create a sub-class or function or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Not like what you are doing.

The structure of CI urls is:

```
domain.com/controller/function/arg1/arg2/etc...
```

So, you want "highlight" to be a value passed into widget($value); then, inside the widget function, some IF statement that says

```
if ($value == 'highlight')
{
    $this->highlight();
}
```

At least, I think this is what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You need to use routes in CI:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

You can map /digital/highlights/ to  /digital/widget/highlights.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Worked it out

```
public function widgets($widget = null) {

switch($widget) {
case 'highlights':
$this->highlights();
break;
default:
$widget = "widgets";

$this->load->view(
```

etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You can using URI Routing https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

```
$routes['digital/widget/highlights'] = 'digital/highlights';
```

but since you said some other functions too maybe for widget() function

If you want show some other functions inside widget segment, i recommedation you to make new controller Widget.php with written functions that work for Widget in it, then custom it to CI URI Routing maybe like this:

```
$route['digital/widget/(:any)'] = 'digital/widget/$1';
```

hope this helps, sorry for my english.